# How to dynamically attach a jQuery plugin to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A user can dynamically create a new div in a web page based on actions like clicking a button. Then based on certain criteria, I would like to attach and execute one of many available jQuery plugins (all already loaded in the page) to the newly created div. How can this be done?

Comment: Most of the plugins do not support event delegation. You need to attach the plugin to new elements once they are added.

Comment: you can add plugin code once you create element

Comment: @Milind How? I know how to attach a plugin like $(#id).somePlugin() in advance but not when the element is created programmatically after the page has rendered and executed the js.

Comment: would be great if you can share both plugin call and how elements are added dynamically,

Comment: @Milind Not sure why it matters how an element is created. jQuery's .appendTo is one. jQuery plugins work the same way. You select an element and call the plugin's contructor and I mentioned this already: $(#id).somePlugin()

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no creation event you can hear for.

But, if you know which events can trigger the creation of those divs (I suppose you can't modify the actual code which creates them), and only in case that they does'nt stop event propagation, you could hear for the same events and, after a minimal delay (with setTimeout()) to ensure it's actions to pe fully permormed, check for matching divs WHITHOUT a given class. Then apply (or not) propper plugin and add that class to avoid doing it again next time.

This could be something similar to:

```
$("#myContainer").on("click", "a, button", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#myContainer div.someClass").not(".managed").each(function(){
            var me = $(this);
            …
            me.addClass("managed");
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how to attach a plugin to a newly created element. You're just adding a new class.

Comment: I guess you know that. This depends on the actual plugin. jQuery plugins usually applies by $(selector).plugin_name(args). For instance, in below code: … me.plugin_name(); … But, better check each plugin documentation to know what actual parameters you need to provide to each plugin.